# Create JIRA Issue using a PHP Script with JIRA SOAP API (Multi select field issue)

Tags: php, soap, jira

I am trying to **create an Issue** in JIRA(v6.2.5) through **PHP** script using **JIRA SOAP API**.

Code:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://jira.xxx.com/jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('username', 'passwd') or die('Username/Password is not correct!');
$issue = array(
    'type' => 2,
    'priority' => 3,
    'project' => 'TEST',
    'versions' => 'TEST',
    'summary' => 'Doing POC',
    "components" => array("id" => "10010"),
    'assignee' => 'samj1'
);
$soapClient->createIssue($token, $issue);
```

**Output** :

Isssue is created in JIRA but with having few fields Not all.

```
Fields      Type        Description
------      --------    -------------
type        select      single selection dropdown for issue type
priority    select      single selection dropdown for priority
project     Text Field  Specific project name 
versions    select      Multiselect dropdown for  affected version
assignee    select      single selection dropdown for assignee
summary     text        Text field to give the summary
components  select      Multiselect dropdown for components
```

Issues I faced:

Except versions and components (muliselect fields), other fields are getting populated while creating the issue trough script.

So could anybody please guide me in solving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use the SOAP API anymore: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/jira-xml-rpc-overview/soap-and-xml-rpc-api-deprecation-notice

Comment: @Koshinae .Thanks for your suggestion. And please tell me the way by which I can create issue in JIRA API and also matches my requirement. It will be better if you provide me example.

Comment: @Koshinae. For a shorter period(may be 1-2months) of time I want to use SOAP API and latterI would be migrating to REST API, So is there any way to create issue with multiselect drop down values using SOAP API.